# How to define Python Enum properties if MySQL ENUM values have space in their names?

Tags: python, mysql, enums, marshmallow

I have Python `Enum` class like this:

```
from enum import Enum
class Seniority(Enum):
    Intern = "Intern"
    Junior_Engineer = "Junior Engineer"
    Medior_Engineer = "Medior Engineer"
    Senior_Engineer = "Senior Engineer"
```

In MYSQL database, seniority ENUM column has values "Intern", "Junior Engineer", "Medior Engineer", "Senior Engineer".

The problem is that I get an error:

```
LookupError: "Junior Engineer" is not among the defined enum values
```

This error has occurred when I call query like:

```
UserProperty.query.filter_by(full_name='John Doe').first()
```

`seniority` is enum property in the `UserProperty` model.

```
class UserProperty(db.Model):
   ...
   seniority = db.Column(db.Enum(Seniority), nullable=True)
   ...
```

For this class I've defined Schema class using `marshmallow` `Schema` and `EnumField` from `marshmallow_enum` package:

```
class UserPropertySchema(Schema):
    ...
    seniority = EnumField(Seniority, by_value=True)
    ...
```

What to do in this situation, because I can't define python class property name with space. How to force python to use values of defined properties instead of property names?

Comment: see if this helps https://www.notinventedhere.org/articles/python/how-to-use-strings-as-name-aliases-in-python-enums.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Shenanigator stated in the comment of my question, we can use aliases to solve this problem.

```
Seniority = Enum(
    value='Seniority',
    names=[
        ('Intern', 'Intern'),

        ('Junior Engineer', 'Junior Engineer'),
        ('Junior_Engineer', 'Junior_Engineer'),

        ('Medior Engineer', 'Medior Engineer'),
        ('Medior_Engineer', 'Medior_Engineer'),

        ('Senior Engineer', 'Senior Engineer'),
        ('Senior_Engineer', 'Senior_Engineer')
    ]
)
```